# In the U.S as F1-visa student, I used TurboTax and filled the wrong form twice

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident

I unfortunately filled my taxes using TurboTax as an International student twice and got money back before I found out it was incorrect for me to use that system.

I have not filled the 8843 form either because I did not know and it is August 2017!

What do I do?
Will this affect any potential applications such as an OPT application?

I need some help and advice.

Answer (score 4):

To start with, I should mention that many tax preparation companies will give you any number of free consultations on tax issues — they will only charge you if you use their services to file a tax form, such as an amended return. I know that H&R Block has international tax specialists who are familiar with the issues facing F-1 students, so they might be the right people to talk about your specific situation.

According to TurboTax support, you should [prepare a completely new 1040NR](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/after-you-file/discussion/non-resident-alien-tax-amendment/00/557512), then submit that with a 1040X. GWU’s tax department says [you can submit late 8843](https://taxdepartment.gwu.edu/frequently-asked-questions-international-students#FAQ21), so you should probably do that if you need to claim non-resident status for tax purposes.

(Updated on Nov 8, 2019): According to the [1040X form instructions on the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040x.pdf) (pg 7):

> Also, use Form 1040X if you should have filed Form 1040 (or, for years before 2018, Form 1040, 1040A, or 1040EZ) instead of Form 1040NR or 1040NR-EZ, or vice versa.
>
> To amend Form 1040NR or 1040NR-EZ, or to file the correct return, do the following:
>
> - Enter your name, current address, and social security number (SSN) or individual taxpayer identification number (ITIN) on the front of Form 1040X.
> - Don’t enter any other information on page 1. Also, don’t complete Parts I or II on page 2 of Form 1040X.
> - Enter in Part III the reason why you are filing Form 1040X.
> - Complete a new or corrected return (Form 1040, Form 1040NR, etc.).
> - Across the top of the new or corrected return, write “Amended.”
> - Attach the new or corrected return to the back of Form 1040X.
>
> For more information, see Pub. 519, U.S. Tax Guide for Aliens.

Comment: Your first link is broken.

Comment: Thanks! I've replaced it with a similar link. I also found a quote from the IRS with specific instructions about what to do in this case!

Answer (score 2):

Read up on filing an "amended tax return".  Essentially you'll fill out the entire return as it should have been originally, then fill out form [1040X](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040x.pdf) stating what has changed (and pay the additional tax due if needed).

According to TurboTax's website, they have partnered with [Sprintax](https://www.sprintax.com/non-resident-alien-tax-1040nr-turbotax.html) for non-resident tax prep.  I am not vouching for the service; just offering it as information.